# dynamic array slicing to limit the length, when the limit is unset

Tags: javascript, slice

I have a class

```
function Thing (n) {
    this.limit = n // null or int n
    this.table = [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

I want to do this for aesthetics

```
Thing.prototype.test = function () {
    let that = this;
    return this.table
               .slice(0, that.limit) // this line
               .map() // etc
}
```

since the above is simplified code and the actual `table` is an instance of another class and has another instance method and a map() called on it, before the slice().

So I was wondering if there was a way to force slice to slice to `Thing.limit` if that existed, and else slice and return the whole array. (Before the last map() the array is managably small). Something like

```
Thing.prototype.test = function () {
    let that = this;
    return this.table
               .slice(0, (that.limit == null) ? this.length : that.limit)
               .map() // etc
}
```

This doesn't work, I get an error

```
ReferenceError: that is not defined
```

As a side question, what is the `this` context inside a slice()? Is this a dumb question to be asking?

Note `this.table.slice(0, -1) => [1, 2, 3]` and `this.table.slice(0, 0) => []`.

I'm amenable to changing how `Thing.limit` is saved and also this is mostly cause now I am curious, as I have already changed the function to `slice` only if `this.plan.limit` exists && > this.table.length.

---

The code to instantiate the class is

```
const gadget = new Gadget();
const query = new Thing(gadget);
const result = query.get();
```

Possibly relevant: in the real code, inside query.get(), there's another function called `getRowIds` that gets called before the slice(), and then a very basic map().

the error occurs at the `slice()` line

Comment: Can you show the code instancing the Thing class into a variable? Because I don't see a reason why it would ever throw this error with the code you posted here.

Comment: yep will add that right away

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `that` as you're within the same scope. If you need it in the map function you can provide it with a context as a second parameter.

Comment: OH MY I apologize, I mixed up this/that and you are right. the code works. if you add an answer I'll accept it! (The actual limit property is off "this.plan", and I'd set `that = this.plan` in my code, and messed up the code in the slice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `undefined` with slice's second parameter will give you the desired behavior. If you accept 0 as a limit for some reason, if having an empty table is a thing, then you can use this.

```
function Thing (n) {
    this.limit = n; // undefined or int
    this.table = [1, 2, 3, 4]
}


Thing.prototype.test = function () {
    return this.table
               .slice(0, this.limit)
               .map() // etc
}
```

---

Now careful with the instanciation, I see you pass an instance of `Gadget` and not a number to the `Thing` constructor, so this may have a different behavior than what you expect.